# Fixed position inside relative container not working as expected?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a fixed div inside a relative container, however top and left on the fixed div don't seem to work as they should inside the relative container?

My understanding of fixed position is that it is relative to the window, not any container?

see example: fixed div inside relative container
[https://jsfiddle.net/jfcb92mx/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/LekhuleniB/jfcb92mx/)

```
<div class="relativecontainer">
<div class="fixedContainer">
    This is experimental
</div>

<div class="otherContainer"></div>
</div>

.fixedContainer {
    background-color:#ddd;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 2em;
    left: 50%;       
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.relativecontainer{
  position: relative;
}

.otherContainer {
    height:1000px;
    background-color:#bbb;
}
```

example 2: fixed div without relative container
https://jsfiddle.net/LekhuleniB/0kmn7xrk/

```
<div class="fixedContainer">
    This is experimental
</div>

<div class="otherContainer"></div>


.fixedContainer {
    background-color:#ddd;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 2em;
    left: 50%;       
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.otherContainer {
    height:1000px;
    background-color:#bbb;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: your code is wrong in html in first fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jfcb92mx/2/

Comment: there is litle mistake in ur fiddle here `<div class="relativecontainer">` u wrote `<div class="relativecontainer"<`

Comment: doh!! I guess I'm having one of those days. It doesn't seem to work on my project, I guess this is not the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is little mistake in your fiddle you wrote this

```
 <div class="relativecontainer"<
```

instead of this

```
    <div class="relativecontainer">
```

try it by correcting it then give relative position to relative container it will work fine

Comment: I thought I had pin pointed the cause of my issues, obviously not. I will accept your answer just for having wasted your time, and technically answering the question. Back to investigating for me :(